# ajv validation fails for JSONSchema having recursive $ref

Tags: node-modules, jsonschema, ajv

I am using **"ajv": "^6.5.1"** for JSONSchema validation. The mentioned JSONSchema having recursive reference for **adressInfo** field which is **required** field.

I am getting validation failed error:

> [{"keyword":"required","dataPath":".billing_address.adressInfo.adressInfo","schemaPath":"#/required","params":{"missingProperty":"street_address"},"message":"should
>   have required property 'street_address'"}]

What should I do for this type of JSONSchema as it will required **adressInfo** in each level. This is my script:

```
var Ajv = require('ajv');

var addressJsonSchema = {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "definitions": {
        "address": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "street_address": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "city": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "adressInfo": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/address"
                }
            },
            "required": ["street_address", "city", "adressInfo"]
        }
    },
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "billing_address": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/address"
        }
    }
}

var ajv = new Ajv({
    schemaId: '$id',
    meta: false,
});

var metaSchema = require('../node_modules/ajv/lib/refs/json-schema-draft-07.json');
ajv.addMetaSchema(metaSchema);
ajv._opts.defaultMeta = metaSchema.$id;

var inputData = {
    "billing_address": {
        "street_address": "Viman Nagar",
        "city": "pune",
        "adressInfo": {
            "street_address": "Chandan Nagar",
            "city": "pune",
            "adressInfo": {}
        }
    }
}
try {
    var validate = ajv.compile(addressJsonSchema);
    var valid = validate(inputData);
    if (!valid) {
        console.log('Validation failed error:');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(validate.errors));
    } else {
        console.log("successfully done validation");
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Remove `adressInfo` from the list of required fields.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a schema which is impossible to satisfy.
By saying `adressInfo` is required, which is an `address`... which must have `adressInfo`, which is an `address`...

Your schema is infinitely recursive.

In your example data, you have... billing_address > address > adressInfo > adressInfo

The deepest `adressInfo` in your example data, according to your schema, must have properties `street_address`, `city`, `adressInfo`.

Should the example data you have included be valid?

Comment: Yeah, that's my point, actually every time i need to put all required keys inside *adressInfo* . i.e Ajv always throw an error for the above schema.

Comment: I'm not clear on what your objective is here. You have created a schema which is impossible to satisfy, which cannot be what you mean. I repeat, should the example data you have included be valid? Can you amend your question to include example data that should pass, example data that should fail, and explain why in both cases, please? =]

Comment: To be clear, it is impossible to create JSON data that will be valid for the schema in your question.